# Connection refused: connect, java socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am new using java socket. I have a problem I can´t solve. 
I have a server with a public IP, on it java server executes, then i have an android app client.
With the socket i get to communicate from the client to the server, the problem comes when i try to do it the opposite way. 
I tried sending a confirmation message from the server to the client. 
It doesn´t matter how many time i try because i always end up having this error:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at server.ServerEntrada.run(ServerEntrada.java:48)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have router port 9000 and 9001 open.

The client sends through the port 9000 the data, and server recives them.
Then the server sends them through port 9001 while the app is waiting through

Comment: Have you added `android.permission.INTERNET` permission into your manifest?

Comment: Yes of course, i can connect with the server and send data, but i cant send data from server to client

Comment: You send your data after the client has connected? Because of exception name it looks like you are trying to connect to the client which is probably not listening yet, or hidden behind NAT.

Comment: I send the data to server, then, on client i have this code: Log.i("A","Server entrada esperando ------");
                socketEntrada= serverEntrada.accept(); I can see that it is waiting , and then send the data as i send client to server, but i get that error

Comment: Add your code to the question, don't put it in the comments section.

Comment: Your server *can't* connect to the client, because *the client isn't a server*. But it doesn't need to. It already has the connection created by the client. You don't need another one. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I suppose he uses `Socket` returned by `ServerSocket::accept`, as seen above.

Comment: @Pavlus No. He is trying to connect from the server to the client, and getting a 'connection refused'. Read the *question*, and specifically the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(password.equals("asd")){
    System.out.println("Abriendo socket");
    socketSalida = new Socket(socketEntrada.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(),puertoSalida);
    DataOutputStream datosSalida = new DataOutputStream(socketSalida.getOutputStream());
    datosSalida.writeUTF("OK");
}
```

The problem is here. Your server is trying to connect to your client, but it can't, as your client is a client, not a server.

And it doesn't need to. It already has a connection to the client, the one it read the password from. Change it to this:

```
if(password.equals("asd")){
    System.out.println("Abriendo socket");
    DataOutputStream datosSalida = new DataOutputStream(socketEntrada.getOutputStream());
    datosSalida.writeUTF("OK");
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, then i have to use the same port to send and revice the data? Thanks for this :)

Comment: No, you have to use the same *connection,* which means you have to use the same *socket*. You don't have access to a port from here. Be precise.

Comment: Ok, true, i was learning, thanks for help, now i know how to do it. :)